# MP3 file won't play using jl library

Tags: java, mp3

EDIT: solved it, apperently you don't have to put underscores instead of spaces.

I'm trying to make a mp3 player. But it seems like my file is not found/recognized when I run my program. I'm following this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LavMuqK5Is0, did exactly what he did, so I think it's either the file naming or location that gives me this problem.

My path is declared in my GUI. it looks like this:

MC.Play("C:\Users\the4th\Desktop\school\HBO_ICT\Programmeren\MP3 Speler\All_Along_The_Watchtower");

```
public class MainClass {
    FileInputStream FIS; 
    BufferedInputStream BIS;

    public Player player;



    public void Stop(){
        if(player !=null){ 
            player.close(); 
        }
    }

    public void Play(String path){
        try {
            FIS = new FileInputStream(path); 
            System.out.println();
            BIS = new BufferedInputStream(FIS);  
            player = new Player(BIS); 
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException | JavaLayerException ex) {

        }

        new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    player.play();
                } 
                catch (JavaLayerException ex) {

                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: All those exception handlers which are completely empty basically make it so you don't see what is wrong. At least put an `ex.printStackTrace()`in there and post the exception you are getting.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to post the exception.

I get the following exception:

Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at AppPackage.MainClass$1.run(MainClass.java:46)

Comment: and with the ex.printStackTrace() i get the following: http://prntscr.com/cxizf5 and http://prntscr.com/cxizq3

Comment: File not found and the filename you put in the code does not end with .mp3. I don't think that's a coincidence.

Comment: Already tried to change that aswell. Didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change path ("\" to "\\" or to "/"):

```
MC.Play("C:\Users\the4th\Desktop\school\HBO_ICT\Programmeren\MP3 Speler\All_Along_The_Watchtower");
```

to

```
MC.Play("C:\\Users\\the4th\\Desktop\\school\\HBO_ICT\\Programmeren\\MP3 Speler\\All_Along_The_Watchtower");
```

Comment: Weird in my program I see double backwards slashes. I copied the text and now they are single now. Even with single forward slashed I get the error.